# Why is the hero component covering the nav dropdown?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, daisyui

I am trying to create a Hero component and Nav component using DaisyUI and I am running into this problem where the nav dropdown is covered by the hero component:

[image: Cropping dropdown]

I have run into this issue a lot with DaisyUI and have not been able to find a solution. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

Layout.tsx
[image: Layout.tsx]

Nav.tsx
[image]

Hero.tsx
[image]

Here is a link to my repo: https://github.com/Radicitus/personal-site/tree/add-hero

Thank you for taking a look!

I expect the dropdown to go over the hero component, not show underneath as it inherently should have a higher z-value.

I have tried having the Hero component passed as a child of Nav.

Comment: Please post relevant code as text, formatted as code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need some `z-index` added to the nav bar to lift it up, so add `z-10`.

```
<div className="w-full navbar px-8 pt-6 sticky top-0 z-10">
```